# Why are gpg key options not displayed when generating a key?

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent, gnupg

I want to generate a GPG key interactively in expert mode.

```
gpg --expert --gen-key
```

I only have the name, email and a prompt for a passphrase, no key size, key type, etc., why would it be so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is version dependent. Try `--full-gen-key` instead of `--gen-key`. You can also try `gpg2` instead of `gpg`.